# org.infinispan.lucene.FileCacheKey NotSerializableException exception when trying to replicate data in Hibernate Search Cache

Tags: lucene, wildfly, hibernate-search, infinispan

Trying to upgrade from wildly 10 to 17 with an existing working hibernate search implementation backed by the in Wildfly infinispan, whenever the second node tried to join the cluster(if the start didn't timeout completely) i would get a stack like:

```
org.infinispan.commons.marshall.NotSerializableException: org.infinispan.lucene.FileCacheKey
    Suppressed: org.infinispan.util.logging.TraceException
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.SimpleAsyncInvocationStage.get(SimpleAsyncInvocationStage.java:41)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.invoke(AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.java:250)
        at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.executeCommandWithInjectedTx(CacheImpl.java:1939)
        at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.executeCommandAndCommitIfNeeded(CacheImpl.java:1917)
        at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.putIfAbsent(CacheImpl.java:1474)
```

Looking into the problem, FileCacheKey is in fact not Serializable

Answer (score 2):

Looking around the web, it appears my problem was that you aren't "supposed" to use the included version of infinispan directly in your app.  You are supposed to include a whole other implementation of infinispan to use directly. Now, this seemed silly, since you are reinstalling the same version, so it should just work with the internally supplied one.  (Note doing this will fix the problem, if you follow the instructions here https://infinispan.org/docs/9.1.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#infinispan_modules_for_wildfly)

However, after starting to go down this road, and being annoyed at having to setup infinispan twice in a single version of wildfly, I found this comment, that gave me hope: https://developer.jboss.org/message/977137#977137

After a bunch of digging, I found this class, which is the key to all your problems. [LifecycleCallbacks](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/master/lucene/lucene-directory/src/main/java/org/infinispan/lucene/LifecycleCallbacks.java)

So if *LifecycleCallbacks* is in the classpath of a Cache Manager, it will register all of the Externalizers(which serialize the non-serializeable classes) that lucene needs to work when backed by infinispan, and everything will work.  However, the newer versions of wildfly, and the hibernate search they provide, do not include this file.  It exists in 
*infinispan-lucene-directory*.  So the solution to this, is to create your own module, that has the provider jars in it, and make sure the cache container module points to that.   The key pieces needed are:

Cache Container in standalone/domain.xml

```
 <cache-container name="luceneContainer" default-cache="lucene-default" statistics-enabled="true" module="org.infinispan.hibernate-search.directory-provider">
            <transport channel="epicenter-localsite-cluster" lock-timeout="60000"/>
             <replicated-cache name="lucene-default">
                <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
                <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="NONE"/>
            </replicated-cache>
             <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesData">
                <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
                <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="NONE"/>
            </replicated-cache>
             <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesMetadata">
                <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
                <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="NONE"/>
            </replicated-cache>
             <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesLocking">
                <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
                <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="NONE"/>
            </replicated-cache>
        </cache-container>
```

Module XML:

```
    <!-- This is derived from the infinispan-feature pack wf modules.  It exists to get the cache to register the correct externalizers for lucene -->
<module name="org.infinispan.hibernate-search.directory-provider" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="infinispan-directory-provider-9.4.14.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="infinispan-lucene-directory-9.4.14.Final.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.apache.lucene"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.search.engine"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="org.infinispan.commons" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.infinispan" export="true" services="export"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

After creating this module, adding it to Wildfly and updating your cache container, everything should work.  In the end, the key issue was that the internally infinispan is "stripped down" to only what wildfly needs, and is in fact, missing the